# Is there any way to get notifications for 'On the House' games?

Tags: origin

EA's [Origin](https://www.origin.com) occasionally offers certain games completely free as part of their 'On the House' promotion. As they've offered [a few pretty good games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Origin%27s_On_the_House_games) in the past, I'd like some way to get notified when a new one is available so I don't miss out.

I'm not really looking for something to tell me about *upcoming* free games, unless it's from an official source, as many websites are happy to post erroneous or out of date information, or even just rumours.

I would prefer something like an RSS feed or email notification. The best solution I've found so far is to simply keep an eye on various gaming blogs and perhaps create a custom filter for 'On the House'. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Concider the many deal sites that monitor for deals - hotukdeals is one that's mainly aimed at UK retail but they list online games too - add a filter for free + steam and you're away (or origin, psn, xbox live, etc).

Comment: You could try turning on the "EA may email me about products news and events ..."  setting under Account & Privacy -> Privacy Settings -> Contact Preferences. I don't know how many other e-mails this will generate though.

Comment: @RossRidge are you sure that includes info on the 'on the house' games?

Comment: Nope, but it would be odd if it didn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use a website monitoring tool** ([like these](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-website-change-notification/)). I used Page Monitor for Chrome.

1. Install the plug-in
2. Visit the '[On the house](https://www.origin.com/en-us/store/free-games/on-the-house)' page
3. Activate the plug-in by clicking the icon in the upper right
4. Drag a selection box around just the free game image and it's title (you don't care about anything else changing)

[image]

5. Set an email to be notified at

Let the free games roll in.

Comment: Really nice answer!

Comment: Sadly this no longer works, VisualPing doesn't load the page correctly.

Comment: @intgr, The answer is general to using a website monitoring tool, with a specific example using VisualPing. Have you tried a different tool?